# No access from PC1 to PC2 with anything except ping

Tags: networking, windows-xp, network-shares

I'm partially a sysadmin at a company and one employee called me this morning that they have a weird network issue.

The topology is the following: 2 PCs connected with a router that is connected to the internet. PC1 hosts a DB server while PC2 is used as a central file storage for excel and word files. Both PCs are running "good ol'" Windows XP Pro SP3. Both PCs have their firewalls turned off (don't ask..).

The issue is that since this morning she can't access the shared docs folder on PC2. I can ping PC2 with exact IP without problem so phisically the connection is there but if I want to ping with the qualified name (let's say it's PC-1 and PC-2), it's not working. If I go to My Network Places, it only shows "My places in MSN network" (or something similar, language is not english) and nothing else. No "Show entire network", nothing. If I want to show the computers of the currently used workgroup, it says that the workgroup is not accessible because I might have no privileges (I'm logged in as admin).

Comment: "I tried almost everything" Please be more specific, exactly what all did you try already?  ie: Did you try rebooting both machines?  Have you tested with another machine plugged into that same router?  Are DNS lookups working as expected from those machines (`nslookup`)?  Is NetBIOS over TCP configured and allowed through the router?

Comment: Ping means you have TCP connectivity in order to get an ICMP message across. You are trying to use SMB, which requires many more things to be functional in order to gain access. Furthermore, if you are using hostnames (I'm guessing that is what you mean, though that is not a qualified name), then there is even more at work (unless you are pinging by hostname, rather than IP - you really didn't specify). "Admin" also doesn't necessarily mean you should have privileges to anything on any other machine (such as anything else in the domain or workgroup).

Comment: All of that said, can you be a bit clearer about what does and doesn't work? Can you ping by hostname? or just IP? Can you connect via SMB by IP instead of hostname? What are the permissions on the share on the server? Can you install wireshark or windump and take a capture of a connection attempt from both sides?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the Windows firewall on PC2 again please. I once have an firewall reactivated after Windows Updates.
2. Since you can ping PC2 by IP, but not by name, you have a problem with DNS. Check the hosts files on both PCs, Check the settings of the DNS Server if you are using one, and check the IP settings of both PCs whether the correct DNS Server is used.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the firewall is your problem. Usually the firewall does not prevent sharing across workgroups. - You don't write if the problem is identical on the two PC's. Is the "Show entire network" missing on both? If it is missing on only one of them, that's the one with the problem. - The network seems to be ok since the ping is working, so maybe it has "lost" the workgroup. Check *system properties / computer name* to restore it.

As others suggests the DNS-settings could be messed up. But in that case the ping should not be working though. - Restarting the router / switch and rebooting the PC's should fix this, if the PC's are set to receive automatic DHCP and DNS address.